# Console how to make a 8x8 pixel display

Tags: c#, visual-studio, console-application, display

My plan is to make a pixel be █ and have it be in a 8 by 8 display like a led matrix then to have the user enter coordinates. Say if a display was:

```
0000                           
0100  
0000
```

The coordinates for the 1 would be A(horizontal) and 2(vertical) so its like algebraic notation in chess. The 1 would be the █ and 0's being space (plus some way to convert the 1 to █ and 0 to a space and vice-versa) after the user makes it I would like to store it in a txt file to be sent and opened else where.

code for displaying an array:

```
            for (int i = 0; i < rowLength; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < colLength; j++)
                {
                    Console.Write(string.Format("{0} ", Master[i, j]));
                }
                Console.Write(Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine);
            }
```

Comment: What have you tried? Your question comes over a bit 'give me code' because there are no questions just tasks in this 'question'.

Answer (score 0):

Suggestions:

1. Store your position information in a 2D array or maybe create a struct(or a class) for the objects you want to display.
2. Use: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.setcursorposition(v=vs.110).aspx to draw on the console.
3. Store the 2D array in a text file (the serialization is up to you).

Comment: I've been working on the code for it and it has space around it like:                █  █  █                                                                                                               and Its the same with the line spacing I need the space gone since the program will be a sort of pixel art sender/receiver

Comment: Not sure if this is possible. It might depend on the console font you are using.

Comment: I put the code i'm using in the main question i have a feeling the problem could be with the code i'm using to display the array